# I am not able to plot .tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, matlab2tikz

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%line width=1.0pt\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth
        \setlength\figureheight{8cm}
        \setlength\figurewidth{8cm}
\begin{figure}
%%%%%% Tikz code is
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
%
%The latest updates can be retrieved from
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz-matlab2tikz
%where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.951\fwidth,
height=\fheight,
at={(0\fwidth,0\fheight)},
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=0.3,
xlabel={time sec},
xmajorgrids,
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=6,
ylabel={Torque},
ymajorgrids,
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=black}
]
\addplot [color=red,solid,line width=1.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   0\\
0.00509999999999989 0\\
0.0101  0\\
0.0151999999999999  0\\
0.0202  0\\
0.0252  0\\
0.0303  0\\
0.0353  0\\
0.0404  0\\
0.0455  0\\
0.0506  1.95\\
0.0557  1.95\\
0.0608  1.95\\
0.0659  1.95\\
0.071   1.95\\
0.076   1.95\\
0.081   1.95\\
0.0861  1.95\\
0.0911  1.95\\
0.0962  1.95\\
0.1001  4\\
0.1051  4\\
0.1102  4\\
0.1152  4\\
0.1202  4\\
0.1252  4\\
0.1303  4\\
0.1353  4\\
0.1404  4\\
0.1454  4\\
0.15    5.6\\
0.155   5.6\\
0.16    5.6\\
0.1651  5.6\\
0.1701  5.6\\
0.1751  5.6\\
0.1802  5.6\\
0.1852  5.6\\
0.1903  5.6\\
0.1953  5.6\\
0.2004  5.6\\
0.2006  4\\
0.2057  4\\
0.2107  4\\
0.2157  4\\
0.2208  4\\
0.2258  4\\
0.2309  4\\
0.2359  4\\
0.241   4\\
0.246   4\\
0.2505  1.9\\
0.2555  1.9\\
0.2605  1.9\\
0.2655  1.9\\
0.2706  1.9\\
0.2756  1.9\\
0.2807  1.9\\
0.2857  1.9\\
0.2907  1.9\\
0.2958  1.9\\
0.3 1.9\\
};
\addlegendentry{Actual };

\addplot [color=black,solid]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   -0\\
0.00509999999999989 -1.89174897968769e-013\\
0.0101  3.49245965480804e-013\\
0.0151999999999999  9.89530235528946e-013\\
0.0202  7.27595761418343e-013\\
0.0252  3.49245965480804e-013\\
0.0303  7.27595761418343e-013\\
0.0353  -2.18278728425503e-012\\
0.0404  -4.65661287307739e-013\\
0.0455  8.14907252788544e-013\\
0.0506  0.0481456716631365\\
0.0507  0.0951026224529778\\
0.0508  0.140900201993907\\
0.0509  0.185567035261629\\
0.051   0.2291310404861\\
0.0511  0.271619446586876\\
0.0512  0.313058810201095\\
0.0513  0.353475032279181\\
0.0514  0.392893374276959\\
0.0515  0.431338473940006\\
0.0516  0.468834360706416\\
0.0517  0.505404470730078\\
0.0518  0.541071661518246\\
0.0519  0.575858226226206\\
0.052   0.609785907588608\\
0.0521  0.642875911511655\\
0.0522  0.6751489203253\\
0.0523  0.706625105709245\\
0.0524  0.737324141305318\\
0.0525  0.767265215010149\\
0.0526  0.796467040969088\\
0.0527  0.824947871274286\\
0.0528  0.852725507372525\\
0.0529  0.879817311190127\\
0.053   0.906240215986443\\
0.0531  0.932010736937285\\
0.0532  0.957144981457474\\
0.0533  0.981658659267967\\
0.0534  1.0055670922157\\
0.0535  1.02888522384866\\
0.0536  1.05162762875925\\
0.0537  1.07380852169069\\
0.0538  1.09544176642376\\
0.0539  1.1165408844387\\
0.054   1.13711906337345\\
0.0541  1.15718916525846\\
0.0542  1.17676373456095\\
0.0543  1.19585500602398\\
0.0544  1.21447491231406\\
0.0545  1.23263509147827\\
0.0546  1.25034689421998\\
0.0547  1.26762139099289\\
0.0548  1.2844693789203\\
0.0549  1.30090138854311\\
0.055   1.31692769040141\\
0.0551  1.33255830145569\\
0.0552  1.34780299134689\\
0.0553  1.36267128850301\\
0.0554  1.37717248609307\\
0.0555  1.39131564783826\\
0.0556  1.40510961367461\\
0.0557  1.41856300528036\\
0.0558  1.43168423146324\\
0.0559  1.44448149341624\\
0.056   1.45696278984536\\
0.0561  1.46913592196725\\
0.0562  1.48100849838511\\
0.0563  1.49258793984575\\
0.0564  1.50388148387684\\
0.0565  1.5148961893121\\
0.0566  1.5256389407005\\
0.0567  1.53611645261181\\
0.0568  1.54633527383168\\
0.0569  1.55630179145615\\
0.057   1.56602223488226\\
0.0571  1.57550267970515\\
0.0572  1.58474905151076\\
0.0573  1.59376712958256\\
0.0574  1.6025625505129\\
0.0575  1.61114081172604\\
0.0576  1.61950727491459\\
0.0577  1.62766716939048\\
0.0578  1.63562559535334\\
0.0579  1.64338752707921\\
0.058   1.65095781602693\\
0.0581  1.6583411938741\\
0.0582  1.66554227547284\\
0.0583  1.67256556173248\\
0.0584  1.67941544243615\\
0.0585  1.68609619898253\\
0.0586  1.69261200706172\\
0.0587  1.6989669392652\\
0.0588  1.70516496763341\\
0.0589  1.7112099661355\\
0.059   1.71710571309278\\
0.0591  1.72285589353836\\
0.0592  1.72846410152243\\
0.0593  1.73393384235786\\
0.0594  1.73926853481098\\
0.0595  1.74447151323751\\
0.0596  1.74954602966853\\
0.0598  1.75932228518592\\
0.06    1.76862174709531\\
0.0602  1.77746766889378\\
0.0604  1.78588216999406\\
0.0606  1.79388629103298\\
0.0608  1.80150004648152\\
0.061   1.80874247469372\\
0.0612  1.81563168551281\\
0.0614  1.82218490555548\\
0.0616  1.82841852128389\\
0.0618  1.83434811998566\\
0.062   1.83998852874499\\
0.0622  1.84535385152197\\
0.0624  1.85045750441941\\
0.0627  1.85765009812912\\
0.063   1.86432298009173\\
0.0633  1.87051370286639\\
0.0636  1.87625710559546\\
0.0639  1.88158551006534\\
0.0643  1.88809600958601\\
0.0647  1.89398695316122\\
0.0651  1.89931729933523\\
0.0656  1.90527267366243\\
0.0661  1.91052827305827\\
0.0667  1.91602636979052\\
0.0674  1.92148059761265\\
0.0682  1.92665028821668\\
0.0692  1.93181522619069\\
0.0705  1.93686100351359\\
0.0723  1.94162220596682\\
0.0751  1.94583971061194\\
0.0794  1.9485801025742\\
0.0843  1.94958289419935\\
0.0893  1.94988049718828\\
0.0943  1.94996576187093\\
0.0993  1.94999019061224\\
0.1001  2.00060664921792\\
0.1002  2.04997184705839\\
0.1003  2.09811821381754\\
0.1004  2.14507584254249\\
0.1005  2.19087408328144\\
0.1006  2.23554156142531\\
0.1007  2.27910619560067\\
0.1008  2.32159521512417\\
0.1009  2.36303517701582\\
0.101   2.40345198260041\\
0.1011  2.44287089369708\\
0.1012  2.48131654840859\\
0.1013  2.51881297651972\\
0.1014  2.55538361452034\\
0.1015  2.59105132024887\\
0.1016  2.62583838718312\\
0.1017  2.65976655837207\\
0.1018  2.69285704002812\\
0.1019  2.72513051477919\\
0.102   2.75660715459788\\
0.1021  2.78730663340821\\
0.1022  2.81724813938426\\
0.1023  2.84645038694187\\
0.1024  2.87493162843611\\
0.1025  2.90270966557061\\
0.1026  2.92980186052306\\
0.1027  2.95622514679705\\
0.1028  2.98199603980716\\
0.1029  3.0071306472006\\
0.103   3.03164467892479\\
0.1031  3.05555345704802\\
0.1032  3.07887192533462\\
0.1033  3.10161465858584\\
0.1034  3.12379587175098\\
0.1035  3.14542942881046\\
0.1036  3.16652885144213\\
0.1037  3.18710732747169\\
0.1038  3.20717771911668\\
0.1039  3.22675257102546\\
0.104   3.24584411811703\\
0.1041  3.26446429323062\\
0.1042  3.28262473458124\\
0.1043  3.30033679303585\\
0.1044  3.31761153920813\\
0.1045  3.33445977037621\\
0.1046  3.35089201723385\\
0.1047  3.36691855047026\\
0.1048  3.38254938719003\\
0.1049  3.39779429717461\\
0.105   3.41266280898982\\
0.1051  3.42716421594011\\
0.1052  3.44130758187579\\
0.1053  3.45510174686139\\
0.1054  3.46855533269921\\
0.1055  3.48167674831845\\
0.1056  3.49447419503145\\
0.1057  3.50695567165775\\
0.1058  3.51912897952818\\
0.1059  3.53100172735495\\
0.106   3.54258133599334\\
0.1061  3.55387504307478\\
0.1062  3.56488990753435\\
0.1063  3.57563281402105\\
0.1064  3.58611047720045\\
0.1065  3.59632944595331\\
0.1066  3.60629610746872\\
0.1067  3.61601669123367\\
0.1068  3.62549727292988\\
0.1069  3.63474377822981\\
0.107   3.64376198649925\\
0.1071  3.652557534413\\
0.1072  3.66113591947444\\
0.1073  3.66950250345329\\
0.1074  3.677662515737\\
0.1075  3.68562105659893\\
0.1076  3.69338310038677\\
0.1077  3.70095349862985\\
0.1078  3.7083369830742\\
0.1079  3.7155381686374\\
0.108   3.72256155629506\\
0.1081  3.72941153589342\\
0.1082  3.73609238889231\\
0.1083  3.74260829104277\\
0.1084  3.74896331499558\\
0.1085  3.75516143284735\\
0.1086  3.76120651862366\\
0.1087  3.76710235070018\\
0.1088  3.77285261416357\\
0.1089  3.77846090311598\\
0.109   3.7839307229204\\
0.1091  3.78926549239221\\
0.1092  3.79446854593631\\
0.1093  3.79954313563046\\
0.1095  3.80931953229193\\
0.1097  3.81861912846036\\
0.1099  3.82746517797152\\
0.1101  3.83587980055544\\
0.1103  3.84388403715266\\
0.1105  3.8514979025239\\
0.1107  3.8587404352981\\
0.1109  3.86562974557999\\
0.1111  3.87218306023345\\
0.1113  3.87841676595909\\
0.1115  3.88434645026806\\
0.1117  3.88998694046028\\
0.1119  3.89535234069944\\
0.1121  3.90045606728049\\
0.1124  3.90764876483311\\
0.1127  3.91432174313525\\
0.113   3.9205125552883\\
0.1133  3.92625604093727\\
0.1136  3.93158452233666\\
0.114   3.93809511585225\\
0.1144  3.94398614447803\\
0.1148  3.94931656760763\\
0.1153  3.95527202791572\\
0.1158  3.9605277031888\\
0.1164  3.96602587929936\\
0.1171  3.9714801858651\\
0.1179  3.97664995110757\\
0.1189  3.98181496364981\\
0.1202  3.98686081382041\\
0.122   3.99162208501139\\
0.1248  3.99583965054867\\
0.1291  3.9985800820748\\
0.134   3.99958288817806\\
0.139   3.99988049546149\\
0.144   3.99996576137582\\
0.149   3.99999019047053\\
0.1501  4.03949668980765\\
0.1502  4.07802565391097\\
0.1503  4.11560333449789\\
0.1504  4.15225321884267\\
0.1505  4.18799821431708\\
0.1506  4.22286066270547\\
0.1507  4.25686235417429\\
0.1508  4.29002454088748\\
0.1509  4.322367950293\\
0.151   4.35391279807253\\
0.1511  4.384678800783\\
0.1512  4.41468518817794\\
0.1513  4.44395071522699\\
0.1514  4.47249367383646\\
0.1515  4.50033190428451\\
0.1516  4.52748280637278\\
0.1517  4.55396335029838\\
0.1518  4.57979008726263\\
0.1519  4.60497915981832\\
0.152   4.62954631195508\\
0.1521  4.65350689894322\\
0.1522  4.67687589692886\\
0.1523  4.69966791229713\\
0.1524  4.72189719079997\\
0.1525  4.74357762645974\\
0.1526  4.76472277025477\\
0.1527  4.78534583858793\\
0.1528  4.80545972154875\\
0.1529  4.82507699096805\\
0.153   4.84420990827834\\
0.1531  4.86287043217651\\
0.1532  4.88107022609617\\
0.1533  4.89882066550196\\
0.1534  4.91613284499594\\
0.1535  4.93301758525422\\
0.1536  4.94948543978942\\
0.1537  4.96554670154618\\
0.1538  4.98121140933631\\
0.1539  4.99648935411259\\
0.154   5.01139008508791\\
0.1541  5.02592291570315\\
0.1542  5.04009692945145\\
0.1543  5.05392098555266\\
0.1544  5.06740372449113\\
0.1545  5.08055357341858\\
0.1546  5.09337875141806\\
0.1547  5.10588727464405\\
0.1548  5.11808696133096\\
0.1549  5.12998543667939\\
0.155   5.14159013762351\\
0.1551  5.15290831748044\\
0.1552  5.16394705048006\\
0.1553  5.17471323618962\\
0.1554  5.18521360382691\\
0.1555  5.19545471646261\\
0.1556  5.20544297512621\\
0.1557  5.21518462280376\\
0.1558  5.22468574834269\\
0.1559  5.23395229025543\\
0.156   5.24299004043287\\
0.1561  5.25180464776279\\
0.1562  5.26040162166176\\
0.1563  5.26878633551829\\
0.1564  5.27696403005143\\
0.1565  5.28493981658673\\
0.1566  5.29271868025031\\
0.1567  5.30030548308499\\
0.1568  5.30770496708978\\
0.1569  5.31492175718382\\
0.157   5.32196036409459\\
0.1571  5.32882518718141\\
0.1572  5.33552051718181\\
0.1573  5.34205053889519\\
0.1574  5.34841933379739\\
0.1575  5.35463088259302\\
0.1576  5.36068906770178\\
0.1577  5.36659767568743\\
0.1578  5.37236039962166\\
0.1579  5.37798084139448\\
0.158   5.38346251396468\\
0.1581  5.38880884355673\\
0.1582  5.39402317180057\\
0.1583  5.39910875782114\\
0.1585  5.40890633933866\\
0.1587  5.41822608716562\\
0.1589  5.42709130552664\\
0.1591  5.43552416208576\\
0.1593  5.44354574337593\\
0.1595  5.45117610752865\\
0.1597  5.45843433442945\\
0.1599  5.46533857342685\\
0.1601  5.47190608871388\\
0.1603  5.47815330250005\\
0.1605  5.48409583607432\\
0.1607  5.48974854886494\\
0.1609  5.49512557559958\\
0.1611  5.50024036164457\\
0.1614  5.50744864533469\\
0.1617  5.51413608357444\\
0.162   5.52034031084014\\
0.1623  5.52609624227215\\
0.1626  5.5314362701654\\
0.163   5.53796097174118\\
0.1634  5.5438647658664\\
0.1638  5.54920673969798\\
0.1643  5.55517510512512\\
0.1648  5.56044216912607\\
0.1654  5.56595225944865\\
0.1661  5.57141838516473\\
0.1669  5.57659935297273\\
0.1679  5.58177555778186\\
0.1692  5.58683234200359\\
0.171   5.59160393058005\\
0.1738  5.59583063532368\\
0.1781  5.59857700519936\\
0.183   5.59958198432095\\
0.188   5.5998802365039\\
0.193   5.59996568718288\\
0.198   5.59999016921324\\
0.2006  5.56049072703079\\
0.2007  5.52196207360842\\
0.2008  5.48438469603081\\
0.2009  5.44773510721314\\
0.201   5.41199039997088\\
0.2011  5.37712823269537\\
0.2012  5.34312681539916\\
0.2013  5.30996489608925\\
0.2014  5.27762174748693\\
0.2015  5.24607715407095\\
0.2016  5.21531139944322\\
0.2017  5.18530525400629\\
0.2018  5.15603996294149\\
0.2019  5.12749723448919\\
0.202   5.09965922851418\\
0.2021  5.07250854535753\\
0.2022  5.04602821495821\\
0.2023  5.0202016862476\\
0.2024  4.99501281680417\\
0.2025  4.97044586276522\\
0.2026  4.94648546898479\\
0.2027  4.92311665943553\\
0.2028  4.90032482785117\\
0.2029  4.87809572859461\\
0.203   4.85641546775572\\
0.2031  4.83527049446577\\
0.2032  4.81464759242779\\
0.2033  4.79453387165687\\
0.2034  4.77491676042229\\
0.2035  4.75578399739033\\
0.2036  4.73712362396231\\
0.2037  4.71892397679723\\
0.2038  4.70117368052228\\
0.2039  4.68386164062534\\
0.204   4.6669770365172\\
0.2041  4.65050931477069\\
0.2042  4.6344481825238\\
0.2043  4.61878360104616\\
0.2044  4.60350577946383\\
0.2045  4.58860516864152\\
0.2046  4.57407245521256\\
0.2047  4.55989855575713\\
0.2048  4.54607461112688\\
0.2049  4.53259198090623\\
0.205   4.51944223801247\\
0.2051  4.50661716342875\\
0.2052  4.49410874106543\\
0.2053  4.48190915275153\\
0.2054  4.47001077334691\\
0.2055  4.45840616597745\\
0.2056  4.44708807738533\\
0.2057  4.43604943339739\\
0.2058  4.42528333450068\\
0.2059  4.41478305153415\\
0.206   4.40454202147757\\
0.2061  4.39455384335472\\
0.2062  4.38481227422884\\
0.2063  4.37531122530295\\
0.2064  4.36604475811051\\
0.2065  4.35700708080881\\
0.2066  4.34819254455561\\
0.2067  4.33959563997918\\
0.2068  4.33121099373343\\
0.2069  4.32303336514242\\
0.207   4.31505764291988\\
0.2071  4.30727884198129\\
0.2072  4.29969210032222\\
0.2073  4.29229267598284\\
0.2074  4.28507594408156\\
0.2075  4.27803739392632\\
0.2076  4.27117262619422\\
0.2077  4.26447735018146\\
0.2078  4.25794738112317\\
0.2079  4.25157863757582\\
0.208   4.24536713886747\\
0.2081  4.23930900260861\\
0.2082  4.23340044226806\\
0.2083  4.22763776480165\\
0.2084  4.22201736834936\\
0.2085  4.21653573998064\\
0.2086  4.21118945349852\\
0.2087  4.20597516730044\\
0.2088  4.20088962228774\\
0.209   4.19109211977327\\
0.2092  4.18177244709604\\
0.2094  4.1729073002201\\
0.2096  4.16447451166034\\
0.2098  4.15645299505256\\
0.21    4.14882269242647\\
0.2102  4.14156452405202\\
0.2104  4.13466034072675\\
0.2106  4.12809287839671\\
0.2108  4.1218457149849\\
0.211   4.11590322932866\\
0.2112  4.11025056211889\\
0.2114  4.10487357874276\\
0.2116  4.09975883394066\\
0.2119  4.09255060837508\\
0.2122  4.08586322405966\\
0.2125  4.07965904682194\\
0.2128  4.07390316180288\\
0.2131  4.06856317696936\\
0.2135  4.06203852800588\\
0.2139  4.05613478148583\\
0.2143  4.05079285072925\\
0.2148  4.04482453342862\\
0.2153  4.03955751189895\\
0.2159  4.03404746600697\\
0.2166  4.02858138436687\\
0.2174  4.02340045833486\\
0.2184  4.01822429526382\\
0.2197  4.01316755181892\\
0.2215  4.00839600171859\\
0.2243  4.00416933105793\\
0.2286  4.00142298332817\\
0.2335  4.00041801230892\\
0.2385  4.00011976253334\\
0.2435  4.00003431254139\\
0.2485  4.0000098307083\\
0.2506  3.94815663053939\\
0.2507  3.89758746302946\\
0.2508  3.84826685271671\\
0.2509  3.80016397261579\\
0.251   3.75324875685861\\
0.2511  3.70749188190809\\
0.2512  3.66286474822724\\
0.2513  3.6193394624058\\
0.2514  3.57688881972301\\
0.2515  3.53548628714477\\
0.2516  3.49510598674093\\
0.2517  3.4557226795087\\
0.2518  3.41731174959894\\
0.2519  3.37984918892907\\
0.252   3.34331158218428\\
0.2521  3.30767609216404\\
0.2522  3.27292044552881\\
0.2523  3.2390229188682\\
0.2524  3.20596232512509\\
0.2525  3.17371800035206\\
0.2526  3.14226979079598\\
0.2527  3.11159804030231\\
0.2528  3.0816835780289\\
0.2529  3.05250770646159\\
0.253   3.02405218973185\\
0.2531  2.99629924221523\\
0.2532  2.96923151741552\\
0.2533  2.94283209712396\\
0.2534  2.91708448084359\\
0.2535  2.89197257547593\\
0.2536  2.86748068526239\\
0.2537  2.84359350197428\\
0.2538  2.82029609534465\\
0.2539  2.79757390373538\\
0.254   2.77541272503749\\
0.2541  2.75379870779242\\
0.2542  2.73271834253581\\
0.2543  2.71215845335313\\
0.2544  2.69210618964428\\
0.2545  2.67254901809164\\
0.2546  2.65347471482653\\
0.2547  2.63487135778804\\
0.2548  2.61672731927253\\
0.2549  2.59903125866535\\
0.255   2.58177211535207\\
0.2551  2.56493910180673\\
0.2552  2.54852169684795\\
0.2553  2.5325096390633\\
0.2554  2.51689292039417\\
0.2555  2.50166177988367\\
0.2556  2.48680669757313\\
0.2557  2.47231838855229\\
0.2558  2.45818779715637\\
0.2559  2.44440609130665\\
0.256   2.43096465698743\\
0.2561  2.41785509286515\\
0.2562  2.4050692050349\\
0.2563  2.39259900190108\\
0.2564  2.38043668918003\\
0.2565  2.36857466503064\\
0.2566  2.35700551530128\\
0.2567  2.34572200889804\\
0.2568  2.33471709326087\\
0.2569  2.32398388995967\\
0.257   2.31351569039261\\
0.2571  2.30330595159452\\
0.2572  2.29334829214608\\
0.2573  2.28363648818611\\
0.2574  2.27416446952059\\
0.2575  2.26492631582962\\
0.2576  2.25591625296674\\
0.2577  2.24712864934915\\
0.2578  2.23855801243844\\
0.2579  2.23019898530762\\
0.258   2.22204634329287\\
0.2581  2.21409499072682\\
0.2582  2.2063399577555\\
0.2583  2.19877639723077\\
0.2584  2.19139958168165\\
0.2585  2.18420490035744\\
0.2586  2.1771878563489\\
0.2587  2.17034406377442\\
0.2588  2.16366924504086\\
0.2589  2.15715922816991\\
0.259   2.15080994418834\\
0.2591  2.14461742458731\\
0.2592  2.13857779884036\\
0.2593  2.13268729198462\\
0.2594  2.12694222226189\\
0.2595  2.12133899881577\\
0.2596  2.11587411945005\\
0.2597  2.11054416843693\\
0.2598  2.10534581438391\\
0.2599  2.10027580814983\\
0.2601  2.09050824170426\\
0.2603  2.08121704509691\\
0.2605  2.07237898549589\\
0.2607  2.06397196314848\\
0.2609  2.05597495612115\\
0.2611  2.04836796772914\\
0.2613  2.04113197653962\\
0.2615  2.03424888880647\\
0.2617  2.02770149322407\\
0.2619  2.02147341789256\\
0.2621  2.01554908937993\\
0.2623  2.00991369377822\\
0.2625  2.00455313966441\\
0.2627  1.99945402286068\\
0.263   1.99226782188125\\
0.2633  1.98560087073239\\
0.2636  1.97941565023077\\
0.2639  1.97367735219997\\
0.2642  1.96835368358047\\
0.2646  1.96184897054819\\
0.265   1.95596326280505\\
0.2654  1.9506376542096\\
0.2659  1.9446875729805\\
0.2664  1.93943664472728\\
0.267   1.93394343466722\\
0.2677  1.92849405452787\\
0.2685  1.92332895871042\\
0.2695  1.91816861130088\\
0.2708  1.91312731863261\\
0.2726  1.90837034790561\\
0.2754  1.90415659175109\\
0.2797  1.90141863542845\\
0.2846  1.90041673508051\\
0.2896  1.90011939660186\\
0.2946  1.90003420769918\\
0.2996  1.90000980066863\\
0.3 1.90000886801156\\
};
\addlegendentry{Estimated};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The typesetting of your "MWE" is not really helpful.

Comment: You have defined the lengths `\figurewidth` and `\figureheight`, but you've used the (undefined) lengths `\fwidth` and `\fheight`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as because it's basically about a typo, defining one length, but using another.